# Applying 'transition' effect to <a> elements not working properly

Tags: html, css

Below is some HTML code that I have for a website I'm working on:

```css
.container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    position: relative;
    top: 10%;
    width: 25vw;
    min-width: 428px;
    height: auto;
    padding: 15px;

    justify-content: left;
    align-items: center;
    
    background-color: white;
}

.container a {
  color: black;
  margin-left: 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: all ease-in-out 0.25s;
}

.container a h2:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.container a img {
    width: 100px;
    height: auto;
}

.container + .container {
  margin-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="main">
      <h1>Contact</h1>
      <p>In need of a commission? Do you just want to talk? Let me know by shooting me an email or DMing me on Instagram.</p>
      <div class="container">
        <a href="https://www.instagram.com/bellapfisterphotography" target="_blank"><img src="./insta.png"></a>
        <a href="https://www.instagram.com/bellapfisterphotography" target="_blank"><h2>@bellapfisterphotography</h2></a>
      </div>
      <div class="container">
        <a href="mailto:mail@gmail.com"><img src="./email.png"></a>
        <a href="mailto:mail@gmail.com"><h2>mail@gmail.com</h2></a>
      </div>
  </div>
```

For some reason, the underline transition I'm applying to the containers  elements is not functioning as intended. Any help on fixing this or explaining why this happens would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Having `<h2>` instead an `<a>` is considered invalid HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you must make underline with after or before and animation it with height or width
as you want
your code must change like below (add this part to your code):

```
.container a h2
{
  position:relative ;
}

.container a h2::after
{
  position:absolute ;
  width:100%;
  height: 0px ;
  background:#000 ;
  bottom:-5px ;
  left:0 ;
  content : " " ;
  transition: all ease-in-out 0.25s;
}

.container a h2:hover::after {
   height: 5px ;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The hover element must be the one with transition property.
I would also advise you to move the `:hover` to the `<a>` tag.

Try this:

```css
.container a h2 {
  transition: all ease-in-out 0.25s;
}

.container a:hover h2 {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because you are applying `text-decoration` on two different elements:

```
.container a {
  ...
  text-decoration: none;
}

.container a h2:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

[`text-decoration`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-decoration) is a shorthand for `text-decoration-line`, `text-decoration-color`, `text-decoration-style`, and `text-decoration-thickness` properties. And `text-decoration: none` actually means `text-decoration-line: none`.

But you cannot meaningfully animate `text-decoration-line` and `text-decoration-style`. You can only meaningfully animate `text-decoration-color` (interpolated) and `text-decoration-thickness`.

So in your case, you can initially set the text decoration to transparent, and then change on hover. You can alternatively animate the thickness, starting with `text-decoration-thickness: 0;`.

```css
.email-address {
  text-decoration-thickness: from-font;
  text-decoration-color: transparent;
}

.email-address:hover {
  text-decoration-thickness: 1px;
  text-decoration-color: currentColor;
  transition: all ease-in-out 0.25s;
}

.email-2:hover {
  text-decoration-thickness: 4px;
  text-decoration-color: red;
  transition: all ease-in-out 0.5s;
}

.email-3:hover {
  text-decoration-thickness: 2px;
  text-decoration-color: green;
  transition: all ease-in-out 1s;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <a class="email-address email-1" href="#">email1@acme.com</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a class="email-address email-2" href="#">email2@acme.com</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a class="email-address email-3" href="#">email3@acme.com</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Additional Reference:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-decoration